# Display '-' instead of '0' in Interactive report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have the following sql query which is used to create a report to show revision history for a product. Intial record is revision 0, if something is edited it becomes revision 1, and so on.
Instead of showing '0' in the report i would prefer to show '-', is there a way this can be achieved?

```
SELECT
product_id,
name,
description,
revision,
revision,reason,
'DETAILS' "VIEW DETAILS"
FROM product_table
WHERE product_id = :P2_product_id
ORDER BY REVISION DESC
--order by case when Revision is null then 1 else 0 end, revision desc
```

product_id - numeric
name - varchar2
description - varchar2
revision - numeric
revision_reason - varchar2

I did try the line which is commented out however the repor continues to show the 0 rather than a -.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is the **decode** function.

### Solution

```
SELECT
product_id,
name,
description,
decode(revision,0,'-',revision)revision,
revision_reason,
'DETAILS' "VIEW DETAILS"
FROM product_table
WHERE product_id = :P2_product_id
ORDER BY REVISION DESC
--order by case when Revision is null then 1 else 0 end, revision desc
```

### Explanation

Replaced the column `revision,` with
   `decode(revision,0,'-',revision)revision,` . Make sure you [read how
   decode works](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) - it's very useful.

#### Note

Your SQL Select query includes this: `revision,reason,`. From looking
   at your column definitions, I think you mean `revision_reason,` instead. I
   updated my solution accordingly.

Comment: These days using CASE is more preferable over DECODE

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old and already answered, but I ran into the same problem today, and using `DECODE` for showing a hyphen instead of 0 causes the column type to switch to `STRING`, which prevents proper ordering of multi-digit numbers.

So, here's an alternative that keeps the column as `NUMBER` :

```
CASE WHEN column = 0 THEN NULL ELSE column END AS column
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `nullif(revision,'-')` and use the 'Show null values as' attribute.